# Installing shared library with python package not separately

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pip, pybind11

I have successfully built a Python package that uses CMake combined with pybind11 to create a shared object (`.so` - assuming only Linux usage at the moment) file. The implementation works but I am unable to remove this shared object file using `pip uninstall .`

My `setup` command in `setup.py` file looks like this taken from the [pybind/cmake_example](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example) repository:

```py
setup(
    name='package',
    version='0.0.1',
    author='-',
    author_email='-',
    description='A test project using pybind11 and CMake',
    long_description='',
    ext_modules=[CMakeExtension('packagebindings')],
    cmdclass=dict(build_ext=CMakeBuild),
    zip_safe=False,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages()
)
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` file has an `install` instruction that looks like this:

```
install(TARGETS packagebindings COMPONENT python LIBRARY DESTINATION ${Python_SITELIB})
```

To summarise, here are the files that are created when running `pip install .`:

- `path/to/site-packages/package/*` - removed by `pip uninstall package`
- `path/to/site-packages/package-0.0.1.dist-info/*` - removed by `pip uninstall package`
- `path/to/site-packages/packagebindings.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` - still present after `pip uninstall package`

I would like to know how make it so that running `pip uninstall .` removes the `.so` file.

If a further MRE is required, I can link to a repository.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking your CMake install target places the .so directly in the python installation directory? That would explain its lack of removal.

Comment: that is what I'm doing for sure - I guess I want the destination directory to be in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIRECTORY}` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Your CMake install target seems to place the .so directly into the python installation directory (`DESTINATION ${Python_SITE_LIB}`). I'm guessing this stops the .so from being registered by Python proper, so it is not removed when uninstalling. I would suggest to make CMake place the .so in a distribution directory, and then add the following option to `setup()`:

```
data_files = [("installation_bin", ["distribution_bin/library.so"])]
```

This will let the .so be tracked by the Python package manager. The first string is a directory relative to the installation prefix. The second string is the .so file in your distribution, relative to the setup.py script.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will try this now and get back to you