# Packaging executable, shared library, and Python bindings not finding library

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda, scikit-build

I have a project, [cloudgen](https://github.com/kprussing/cloudgen), that I would like to add bindings for Python so I can access some of the underlying functions. I have stubbed out the initial work [on a branch](https://github.com/kprussing/cloudgen/tree/feature/python-bindings).  Because the main executable is built with cmake, I decided to use [scikit-build](https://scikit-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to manage the build and use [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to deal with the binding ([following this example repo](https://github.com/pybind/scikit_build_example)).

When I run `pip install .` in a virtual environment, everything appears to work as expected.  I find the executable is installed to `<prefix>/bin`, the library goes into `<prefix>/lib`, and the module goes into `<prefix>/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/cloudgen`.  In fact, if I run `pip uninstall cloudgen`, all of the correct files are uninstalled.  However, my problems arise when I start to test the Python bindings.  I find two separate but related problems.

- If I installed into an Anaconda environment, the module is able to resolve the path to the shared library and pass the tests, but the executable does not resolve the path to the library.
- On the other hand, if I installed into a virtual environment using `python -m venv`, both the module and the executable are unable to resolve the path to the shared library.

Searching around, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50137309/4249913) which notes I could manipulate `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or equivalently `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on macOS or `PATH` on Windows), but that [is normally frowned upon](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/use-shared-libraries.html). That question references [an open issue](https://github.com/scikit-build/scikit-build/issues/272) that refers to including additional build products (which as I said appears to not be my problem) but doesn't address the library path resolution.  I also came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64434365/4249913) asking about distributing the build products using scikit-build and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24146840/4249913) using setuptools directly.  Neither of the questions or answers address the library path resolution.

My question is: What is the correct way to distribute a package that contains an executable, shared library, and Python binding module and have the path resolution Just Work™?

A minimal working example is a bit much, but I [created a gist](https://gist.github.com/kprussing/db21614ca5b51cedff07dfb70059f280) to demonstrate the behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit more digging (and carefully reading the [CMake documentation on `RPATH`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling#always-full-rpath)), the correct answer appears to be explicitly setting `RPATH` on installation.  The relevant change to the [linked gist](https://gist.github.com/kprussing/db21614ca5b51cedff07dfb70059f280) is to add the following to the CMakeLists.txt after creating the targets (adapted from the linked Wiki):

```
if (SKBUILD)
    find_package(PythonExtensions REQUIRED)
    set(lib_path "${PYTHON_PREFIX}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}")
else()
    set(lib_path "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}")
endif()
list(FIND CMAKE_PLATFORM_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "${lib_path}" is_system)
if ("${is_system}" STREQUAL "-1")
    set_target_properties(mwe.exe PROPERTIES
        INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE
        INSTALL_RPATH "${lib_path}")
    # The following is necessary for installation in a virtual
    # environment `python -m pip venv env`
    set_target_properties(_mwe PROPERTIES
        INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE
        INSTALL_RPATH "${lib_path}")
endif()
```

This does require following the rest of the details about setting the `RPATH` such as including (literally from the linked CMake Wiki):

```
# use, i.e. don't skip the full RPATH for the build tree
set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE)

# when building, don't use the install RPATH already
# (but later on when installing)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")

# add the automatically determined parts of the RPATH
# which point to directories outside the build tree to the install RPATH
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

earlier in the CMakeLists.txt.  The net result is this should disable the dynamic searching of the library path (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` as appropriate) for the installed executable and Python module.